# Integrable function that is not mean-square integrable

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given that $X=I$, $\mathscr{F}$ is the Borel sets, and $\mu$ is Lebesgue Measure,
I must show that there exists an integrable function on $X$, that is not mean-square integrable.

I know that a function that is integrable on $X$ satisfies:
$$\int_X \!|f| d\mu_L < \infty $$

But I'm having trouble coming up with, or finding a process to create a function such that the following is false:
$$ \int_X f^2 d \mu < \infty $$

Where do I begin?

Answer (score 1):

Consider $x^{\alpha}$ for a suitable $\alpha$. When does
$$\int_0^1 x^{\alpha} dx$$
exist?

Comment: I see that $\alpha$ must be between $(-1,-1/2)$, but from there I'm not sure how to show this using the Lebesgue Integral, it's much easier to do in terms of the Riemann Integral.

Comment: @F00zyBear They coincide in this case, in fact they coincide whenever they both exist in an appropriate sense. I'm pretty sure that if $\alpha=5$, then that integral exists. Perhaps you mean $(-1,\infty)$? In such case, what happens to $x^{-1/2}$ when squared? Is it integrable?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
  \lVert f \rVert_1 &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \, dx = 2 \\
  \lVert f \rVert_2 &= \int_0^1 \frac{1}{x} \, dx = \infty
\end{align*}